# secure script action in php

Tags: php, security

Hi I want to ask about the security of "script action" in this example

```
<form method="post" action="chek_user.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
```

And the action is

```
$username= htmlentities($_POST['username']);    
$mdp=htmlentities(md5($_POST['pass']));

  if($user->check_login($username,$mdp)==0)
    {
        $_SESSION["IP"]=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $_SESSION["USER_AGENT"]=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $_SESSION["timestamp"] = time();  
      if (isset($_POST['remembre']))
       {
       $expire = time() + 24*3600;
       setcookie('user', $_SESSION['user'], $expire); 
       }
        header('location:indes.php');
    }
  else if ($user->check_login($username,$mdp)==-2)
    {
    echo 'no';
    }
```

Comment: If it's security, you're concerned about, you'll need to let us know, what `check_login` does.

Comment: I mean this chec_user.php  $username=htmlentities($_POST['username']);    
$mdp=htmlentities(md5($_POST['pass']));

  if($user->check_login($username,$mdp)==0)
    {
        $_SESSION["IP"]=$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
        $_SESSION["USER_AGENT"]=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $_SESSION["timestamp"] = time();  
      if (isset($_POST['remembre']))
       {
       $expire = time() + 24*3600;
       setcookie('user', $_SESSION['user'], $expire); 
       }
        header('location:indes.php');
    }
  else if ($user->check_login($username,$mdp)==-2)
    {
    echo 'no';
    }

Answer (score 4):

**NEVER** use `setcookie()` to setup a session state.   You should have a `session_start()` in your header file.

**NEVER** use `md5()`  its [extremely broken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security),  `sha1()` is on the NIST list of approved message digest functions (but its [kind of broken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHA-1)),  however the sha2 family is better,  `sha256()` is a great choice but you'll need to find the source code online for it because PHP doesn't have a secure hash function.  You also need a salt,  try searching SO for one of the 10,000+ posts relating to password storage.

**ALWYAS** `die()` after you do a `header("location: ...");`.  This function only modifies the HTTP response header,  **the script still executes**.

The entire session must be over HTTPS.  Currently you are probably violating [OWASP A9](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A9).  And yes,  StackOverflow volates OWASP,  and [they don't care](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69171/why-doesnt-the-stack-overflow-team-fix-the-firesheep-style-cookie-theft/69177).

Comment: Worth noting that a useful way to get around rainbow attacks against md5 and sha1 is to XOR (or even append) against a long secret key -- effectively salting the string and rendering rainbow table attacks ineffective.

Comment: @inf `session_start();$_SESSION['some_var']=1;`

Comment: About the $_SESSION['user']=$data['user']; to for exemple die:hello $_SESSION['user']; , it not secure?

Comment: @inf  If user can be `<script>alert(1)<script>`  then its insecure.  My concern with more with just about every other line that you posted.

Comment: but I filtring this injection